# Coded UI test for msaccess

Tags: ms-access, testing, coded-ui-tests

I am bit curious about hand coding codedui test cases for msaccess application, is it possible to write codedUI framework for ms access vba applications.

any help would be highly appreciated

Thanks
Steave

Answer (score 0):

It proofes as quite difficult as Access isn't supported by VSTO. Therefore it gets real tricky to code an extended UI Coded Test for Access.